# vba, excel : returning the earliest date value in this array of string

Tags: excel, vba

i'm having some issues with the coding and not sure where to fix  this:

I would like the BronzeDate to return the earliest date found in my array.

This is examples of the print out:

```
   Possible Bronze Date : 6/6/2011
   Possible Bronze Date : 10/5/2011
   Possible Bronze Date : 10/5/2011
   Possible Bronze Date : 12/5/2011
   Possible Bronze Date : 10/5/2011
   Possible Bronze Date : 6/6/2011
   Possible Bronze Date : 11/5/2011
   Possible Bronze Date : 1/16/2012
   Possible Bronze Date : 6/6/2011
   Possible Bronze Date : 
   Possible Bronze Date : 
   Possible Bronze Date : 
   Possible Bronze Date : 
   Possible Bronze Date : 
   Possible Bronze Date : 
   Possible Bronze Date : 
   Possible Bronze Date : 
   Possible Bronze Date : 
   Possible Bronze Date : 
  [BRONZE] 0
```

CODING:

```
    Dim Bronze(1 To 100) As String
...
        Dim c As Integer
        c = 1
        Do Until c = 20
            Debug.Print "       Possible Bronze Date : " & Bronze(c)
            c = c + 1
        Loop

        '   EXTRACT THE MIN VALUES
        Dim BronzeDate As String
        BronzeDate = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Bronze)

        '   PRINT OUT VALUE FOR EACH DATES
        Debug.Print "      [BRONZE] " & BronzeDate
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you have no choice but to individually convert the string dates.

I have tested this code to output the correct date.  Note I have switched the middle endian dates in your array to little endian so my version of Excel will process them correctly.

```
Sub ExtractMinDate()

  Dim Bronze() As Variant
  Dim DateCrnt As Date
  Dim DateMin As Date
  Dim InxBronze As Long

  Bronze = Array("6/6/2011", "5/10/2011", "5/10/2011", "1/12/2011", "5/10/2011", _
                 "6/6/2011", "5/11/2011", "16/1/2012", "5/6/2011")

  DateMin = 0

  For InxBronze = LBound(Bronze) To UBound(Bronze)
    If IsDate(Bronze(InxBronze)) Then
      DateCrnt = Bronze(InxBronze)
      If DateMin = 0 Or DateMin > DateCrnt Then
        DateMin = DateCrnt
      End If
    End If
  Next

  Debug.Print DateMin

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that your Bronze array is a String Array.

If you change the Bronze Array to being of type Variant, this should resolve your issue.