# Combine 2 cells based on 2 criteria + Select earliest and latest date VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to VBA and would like to learn it and get my file working. So if someone can help me with my code that would be great and it would be really nice if you can also explain in brief what a line does.

My issue: I have demand history of around 5000 products.

[image]

Articlecode: 60012

Date: 19-4-2014

Demand: -1

---

What I would like to do is the following:

1. Commbine two rows and sum the demand if:

   - article codes are the same and
   - date is the same

Checking the conditions and copying an entire row works. My code:

```
        Sub AddDuplicateDates() 

        'Define variables lastrow
        Dim i, Lastrow
        Lastrow = Sheets("Data").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        'Loop trough data and combine if date is the same
        For i = 2 To Lastrow
            If Sheets("Data").Cells(i, "A").Value = Sheets("Data").Cells(i - 1, "A").Value Then
            If Sheets("Data").Cells(i, "B").Value = Sheets("Data").Cells(i - 1, "B").Value Then


'Here I would like to copy cell Sheet("Data").Cells(i, "C") and add this
'to Sheet("Datacorrected").Cells(i,"C") thus offset(0). How does this work? 


            Else        
            Sheets("Data").Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("DataCorrected").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            End If
            End If
            Next i

            End Sub
```

2. Select the latest and earliest date

   - I already managed to select only unique values (article codes) to a different sheet: Sheet(Results)
   - I already found some topics, but unfortunately all these operate on the same worksheet and don't have a criteria to be met (Article code). For example: [vba, excel : returning the earliest date value in this array of string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9604373/vba-excel-returning-the-earliest-date-value-in-this-array-of-string) . The problem is that I'm new with VBA and don't understand all the code, so I don't get how it works so i can translate it to my problem. Can some one help me with this or point out where i can find a clear explanation?

Comment: Does it have to be done in VBA?  Couldn't you just use a Pivot and report on the data instead of changing it?  Example screenshot in answer...

Comment: Do you want to change the data or create a summary on another sheet?

Comment: Yes, because I'm talking about +/- 60.000 lines and with a pivot table it would be too time consuming.

Comment: Yes my final goal is to create a summary. That contains the following collumns; Articlecode, #demand occurrences, earliest date, latest date, demand volume.

I want to classify each article to a demand pattern: http://kourentzes.com/forecasting/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/tsID.fig3_.png The remaining operations I can do myself, however the operations i mention are a bit harder.

Comment: @user78820  too time consuming using a pivot table?  (10 seconds to setupup < 1 seconds for the system to generate results.  I guess I don't understand why it's too time consuming (you could record a macro creating the pivot table and see how the macro generates the pivot...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is in the click event of a command button. You can change it to some other sub if needed.

In you VBA IDE go to the tools menu and selecte references. Select "Microstoft ActiveX data objects 2.8 Library.

This assumes your first list is on sheet 1. It will write data out to sheet 2.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim dEarliest As Date
    Dim dLatest As Date
    Dim lLastCode As Long
    Dim ws1 As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Excel.Worksheet

    Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim lRow As Long

    'Add fields to your recordset for storing data.  You can store sums here.
    With rs
        .Fields.Append "Articlecode", adBigInt
        .Fields.Append "Date", adDate
        .Fields.Append "Demand", adInteger
        .Open
    End With

    lRow = 1

    ws1.Activate
    'Loop through and record what is in the columns
    Do While lRow <= ws1.UsedRange.Rows.count

        'Filter to see if we already have this Articlecode and date
        rs.Filter = ""
        rs.Filter = "Articlecode=" & Trim(str(ws1.Range("A" & lRow).Value)) & " AND Date='" & Trim(str(ws1.Range("B" & lRow).Value)) & "'"

        If rs.RecordCount = 1 Then
            'If we find that we already have this record, add the demand to the current record.
            rs.Fields("Demand").Value = rs.Fields("Demand").Value + ws1.Range("C" & lRow).Value
            rs.Update
        Else
            'If we don't have this # and date, create a new record.
            rs.AddNew
            rs.Fields("Articlecode").Value = ws1.Range("A" & lRow).Value
            rs.Fields("Date").Value = ws1.Range("B" & lRow).Value
            rs.Fields("Demand").Value = ws1.Range("C" & lRow).Value
            rs.Update
        End If

        lRow = lRow + 1
        ws1.Range("A" & lRow).Activate
    Loop

    rs.Filter = ""
    rs.Sort = "Articlecode, Date"

    ws2.Activate

    lRow = 1

    'Here we loop through the data we collected and write it out.
    Do While rs.EOF = False
        ws2.Range("A" & lRow).Value = rs.Fields("Articlecode").Value
        ws2.Range("B" & lRow).Value = Format(rs.Fields("Date").Value, "mm/dd/yyyy")
        ws2.Range("C" & lRow).Value = rs.Fields("Demand").Value
        lRow = lRow + 1
    rs.MoveNext
    Loop

    'Now let's find the earliest and latest dates for each Articlecode

    ws2.Range("E1").Value = "Articlecode"
    ws2.Range("F1").Value = "Earliest"
    ws2.Range("G1").Value = "Latest"

    lRow = 1

    rs.MoveFirst
    Do While rs.EOF = False

        If rs.Fields("Articlecode").Value <> lLastCode Then
            'The first time we have an Articlecode we will write a line for it.
            lRow = lRow + 1
            ws2.Range("E" & lRow).Value = rs.Fields("Articlecode").Value
            ws2.Range("F" & lRow).Value = Format(rs.Fields("Date").Value, "mm/dd/yyyy")
            ws2.Range("G" & lRow).Value = Format(rs.Fields("Date").Value, "mm/dd/yyyy")
        Else
            'For other occurrences of this Articlecode we will just evaluate the dates.
            If rs.Fields("Date").Value < ws2.Range("F" & lRow).Value Then
                ws2.Range("F" & lRow).Value = Format(rs.Fields("Date").Value, "mm/dd/yyyy")
            End If
            If rs.Fields("Date").Value > ws2.Range("G" & lRow).Value Then
                ws2.Range("G" & lRow).Value = Format(rs.Fields("Date").Value, "mm/dd/yyyy")
            End If
        End If

        'Record the this articlecode
        lLastCode = rs.Fields("Articlecode").Value

        rs.MoveNext
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect! Creating a recordset is something new for me, but I understand the concept. It's nice to see how this gives you the opportunity to work with updating and creating new records. Now I can try to reproduce it and create a module to the find earliest date, latest date for each articlecode. Thank you very much :).  P.S. I wanted to edit the code but an edit has to be 6 characters long. You made a typo yyy instead of yyyy in this line:  ws2.Range("B" & lRow).Value = Format(rs.Fields("Date").Value, "mm/dd/yyy")

Comment: Typo fixed.  Yes, recordsets are very useful.  I have used them for many years.  During the loop where you are writing the summary, you can very easily look at the dates. Let me know if you need help with that.

Comment: I added the date collection for you.  Be sure to clear the summary tab before rerunning.  I added the dates to the cells A1 and A2 so if you run it over an old summary it may look bad.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm trying to solve it myself, but you are way faster. Only thing is, your solution is not exactly what i'm looking for. I want the earliest date and latest date of each articlecode. Such that in the end i can find the average demand interval: # Total days (latest day-earliest date) / # demand occurences. Therefore i was trying to create a new sub that writes the earliest and latest date for each article code.

Comment: I applaud you for trying it yourself.  Let me know if you don't get it figured out. Just leave another comment here.

Comment: Okay I thought i figured it out but no: I created exactly the same sub as you did only i've changed the field "if we find that we already have this record" into:   'If we find that we already have this record, change date if smaller
        If rs.RecordCount = 1 Then
            If rs.Fields("EarliestDate").Value > ws2.Range("B" & lRow).Value Then
            rs.Fields("EarliestDate").Value = ws2.Range("B" & lRow).Value
            rs.Update
            End If

Comment: Made the change for the dates I think you are looking for.  I added another loop through the recordset to analyze the the dates.  You could do it in the first loop but this keeps it clean. If you ever have so much data that it takes a while to process, it would be a good exercise to combine them.

Comment: @user78820 If this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Thank you very much :)! Ofcourse i will mark this as solved. I have 1 questions for my understanding. What does this line say `If rs.Fields("Articlecode").Value <> lLastCode`?

Comment: Glad to help.  That line  - We are in a loop.  At the bottom of the loop we record the Articlecode (of the current record) in the variable lLastCode. then we increment to our next record. At the top of the loop, that line is checking if the record we are now on, is a different Articlecode then the record that we previously looked at. Does that make sense? I can comment it better if you would like me to.

Answer (score 1):

Does this have to be done in VBA?  or would reporting on the data using a pivot table meet the need?  Code isn't always the answer...

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this would work, only I want to do other operations afterwards and then it would be too time consuming. I want to find the average demand interval: # Total days (latest day-earliest date) / # demand occurences